# Mongodb get new values from collection without timestamp

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to fetch added new values  from mongodb collections without timestamp value. I guess only choice using objectid field. I using test dataset on github. "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/primer-dataset.json"
For example if I add new data to this collection, how ı fetch or how ı find these new values.
Some mongodb collections using timestamp value, and I use this timestamp value for get new values. But ı do not know, how ı find without timestamp.
Example dataset ;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTstM.png)

I want like this filter. but it doesn't work

```
{_id: {$gt: '622e04d69edb39455e06d4af'}}
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't have _id in some documents? Or what are you saying? It's not clear what your issue is.

Comment: I fetching events periodically with python. normally ı use timestamp value for fetching new events from mongodb. for example : {time_field : {"$gte" : 1647190876, "$lte":1647190900}}. But some datasets not include timestamp value but always include _id field. this _id field Can it be used to fetching new events? For example my new filter it should look like, {_id : {"$gte" : "622e04d69edb39455e06d4ab"}}, I hope I was able to explain.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new field in the document.

```
SomeGlobalObj = ObjectId[] // length limit is 10
 // you will need Redis or other outside storage if you have multi server
```

```
SomeGlobalObj.shift(newDocumentId)
SomeGlobalObj = SomeGlobalObj.slice(0,10)
//Make sure to keep the latest 10 IDs.
```

Now, if you want to retrieve the latest document, you can use this array.

If the up-to-date thing you're talking about is, disappears after checking, you can remove it from this array after query.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mentioned that you want to do this using Python, so I shall answer from that perspective.

In Mongo, an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) is composed of 3 sections:

> - a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId's creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch
> - a 5-byte random value generated once per process. This random value is unique to the machine and process.
> - a 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value

Because of this, we can use the ObjectId to sort or filter by created timestamp. To construct an ObjectId for a specific date, we can use the following code:

```py
gen_time = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
dummy_id = ObjectId.from_datetime(gen_time)
result = collection.find({"_id": {"$lt": dummy_id}})
```

Source: [objectid - Tools for working with MongoDB ObjectIds](https://api.mongodb.com/python/1.5.2/api/pymongo/objectid.html)

This example will find all documents created before 2010/01/01. Substituting `$gt` would allow this query to function as you desire.

If you need to get the timetamp from an `ObjectId`, you can use the following code:

```py
id = myObjectId.generation_time
```